# function to normalizeImage(src)

Tags: python, image

I am trying to make a function to scale image so the values in the image can fit in `[0...255]`
The result should be equivalent to the library call
`cv2.normalize(src=src, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)`

my code is :

```
def normalizeImage(src):
    image *= 255.0/image.max() 
    return image
```

I am new to python and is there any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: Can you please fix your formatting and indentation? Also, please explain exactly what it is you are trying to achieve. Understandably you are trying to mimic some existing functionality. But a brief explanation of what the inputs/outputs should look like and what issues you are facing would be needed here.

Comment: `src` is never used and `image` is never defined. What library are you using? We need some more info